# Android sensor values to be used in another function

Tags: android, eclipse, orientation, accelerometer, sensors

In the following code, I want the aX, oX etc values to be used for another function of another class. In this case, functions from matrixFunction. However, the scope of the sensor values is only within the while statement. How do I extract the sensor values in a variable to be used in another function? In my case matX.aEx etc. Thanks,

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     double oX = 0.0;       
     double oY = 0.0;
     double oZ = 0.0;


    while (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    {
         oX = event.values[0];      
         oY = event.values[1];
         oZ = event.values[2];
         double timestamp_o = event.timestamp;

         String orientX = String.valueOf(oX);
         String orientY = String.valueOf(oY);
         String orientZ = String.valueOf(oZ);
         String timestamp_oS = String.valueOf(timestamp_o);

     {orientationX.setText("X: "+orientX +"\nY: "+orientY 
             + "\nZ: "+orientZ + "\nTimestamp: "+timestamp_oS);}

    }


    double aX = 0.0;        
    double aY = 0.0;        
    double aZ = 0.0;
    double timestamp_a = 0.0;

    while (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)
    {
          aX = event.values[0];     
          aY = event.values[1];
          aZ = event.values[2];
          timestamp_a = event.timestamp;

         String acX = String.valueOf(aX);
         String acY = String.valueOf(aY);
         String acZ = String.valueOf(aZ);
         String timestamp_aS = String.valueOf(timestamp_a);

     { acceleration.setText("X: "+acX +"\nY: "+acY 
             + "\nZ: "+acZ + "\nTimestamp: "+timestamp_aS);}

    }

    double pressure_mbars = 0.0;

    while (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE)
    {
        pressure_mbars = event.values[0];
        double timestamp_p = event.timestamp;
        String timestamp_pS = String.valueOf(timestamp_p);

         // This is pressure in millibar. 


         String pressure_s = String.valueOf(pressure_mbars);
         pressureT.setText("Pressure: "+pressure_s +"\n"+timestamp_pS);



    }

    matrixFunction matX = new matrixFunction();

    double aEx = matX.aEx(aX, aY, aZ, oX, oY, oZ);
    double aEy = matX.aEy(aX, aY, aZ, oX, oY, oZ);
    double aEz = matX.aEz(aX, aY, aZ, oX, oY, oZ);

    String aEx_s = String.valueOf(aEx);
    String aEy_s = String.valueOf(aEy);
    String aEz_s = String.valueOf(aEz);


    accelerationInE.setText(aEx_s+"\n"+aEy+"\n"+aEz);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple option is to create variables in your class and in `onSensorChanged()` set them to be the sensor readings. In the case you don't have access to the instance and don't want to pass it on you can also make the variables static.

Comment: yes have to define variables outside the onSensorChanged function.